# Geometric and physical interpretation of Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to develop a better understanding (vision) of Functioanl Analysis. I'd be appreciated if someone could point out some books that would give me a better understanding beyond just the theorems and tricks for their proofs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Reed and Simon's  "Methods of modern mathematical physics".